# Use `becomes` on a ActiveRecord::Relation (STI)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

```
# Models
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :zoo
end

class Dog < Animal
  belongs_to :leg
end

class Snake < Animal
end

class Leg < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Zoo
  has_many :animals
end

# Test, which fails with
# Association named 'leg' was not found on Animal; perhaps you misspelled it?
Zoo.first.animals.
         .where(:type => 'Dog')
         .includes(:leg)
```

In this example, Rails can not know the specific type of the objects queried (it would have to analyze the `where` statement for that, which it does not appear to do). Therefore, it fails, as the association is not defined on the generic model `Animal`, but on the `Dog` model.

Is there a way of specifying the type of the objects about to be retrieved, so that the example works?

Comment: cant you define a specific `has_many` instead of just `animals` something like `animals_with_legs`?

Comment: hmm I hope there is a better solution to that...

Comment: `has_many :animals_with_legs, ->{ where(type: ['Dog', ...]) }` then `Zoo.first.animals_with_legs.where(:type => 'Dog').includes(:leg)` is it that terrible?

Comment: `animals.where(:type => 'Dog').includes(:leg)` or with `scope` which I wrote should work, which `active_record/rails` version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that looks inefficient at first, but is actually very performant due to the way ActiveRecord builds up its query object.

A good solution to your query is:

```
Dog.where(id: Zoo.first.animals.where(type: 'Dog').select(:id))
   .includes(:leg)
```

At first glance, it looks like it should execute 2 queries, but ActiveRecord is smart enough to produce the following SQL in a single DB call:

```
SELECT "animals".*
FROM "animals"
WHERE "animals"."id" IN (
  SELECT "animals"."id"
  FROM "animals"
  WHERE "animals"."id" = 111
    AND "animals"."type" = 'Dog'
)
```

Since the outer query is driven by the `Dog` class, then the `.includes` will work. And so this is a generic way of behaving like the [becomes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/becomes) method on an ActiveRecord::Relation.

*Note:* The `.select(:id)` part of the code isn't *actually* required. I just included that for clarity, to show how AR uses that part of the query.

Comment: That's a very clever solution, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a (at least temporary) solution. This monkey patch extends Rails with the functionality to specify a class override when accessing collection associations.

Usage:

```
Zoo.first.animals(false, Dog)
         .includes(Leg)
```

The monkey patch (rails 3!):

```
# This monkey patch extends the rails collection association reader (i.e. )
# zoo.animals by a second option called `class_override`. Using this option,
# a custom model class for the objects to be retrieved can be specified.
#
# Might only work with rails 3.
#
# @see http://stackoverflow.com/q/25887230
module ActiveRecord
  module Associations
    class CollectionAssociation < Association #:nodoc:
      # Implements the reader method, e.g. foo.items for Foo.has_many :items
      def reader(force_reload = false, class_override = nil)
        if force_reload
          klass.uncached { reload }
        elsif stale_target?
          reload
        end

        if class_override.nil?
          association = self
        else
          reflection = self.reflection.dup
          reflection.instance_variable_set(:@klass, class_override)
          association = self.dup
          association.instance_variable_set(:@reflection, reflection)
        end

        CollectionProxy.new(association)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Probably, this can be achieved using association extensions as well. I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

Just stubled across a nice blog post by Robert Pankowecki explaining a possible solution: http://blog.arkency.com/2013/07/sti/.